# Is the function $\sqrt{|x|}$differentiable at x=0.

Tags: calculus

Is the function $\sqrt{|x|}$differentiable  at x=0.I feel that the answer is no because the absolute function is not differentiable at 0. but how can I prove this, Could anyone help me?

Comment: By contradiction: If $f$ is differentiable then so is $f^2$.

Comment: I could not make a link between what u said and the question.@JohnMa

Comment: Well, you might want to think a little bit more... BTW there is only one function in your question.

Comment: For intuition (before thinking about a proof) try drawing the graph. What happens at the origin? Is there a nice tangent there?

Comment: Careful with that line of reasoning.  The absolute function is not differentiable at zero, but $g(x) = |x|^3$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition:

$$\frac d{dx}\sqrt{|x|}\bigg|_{x=0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{|h|}-\sqrt{|0|}}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{|h|}}{h}$$

Now consider the left and right derivatives, noting neither exist.

Comment: $\sqrt{-h}$ refused ?

Comment: @weakmathematician What do you mean?

Comment: I mean after substituting by the value of |h|, when $h<0$

Comment: Yes, you'll get $|h|=-h$ and so $$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{\sqrt{-h}}h=-\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{\sqrt{-h}}{-h}=\dots$$

Comment: it is refused $\sqrt{-h}$?

Comment: @weakmathematician No, when $h<0$, then $-h>0$.

Comment: so the answer will be $-\infty$

Comment: @weakmathematician Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the comment of @JohnMa just observe that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt x}x=+\infty$$

Comment: and the case that $x$ tends to $$0^-$$